# Player data archive not found at '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/...../GameName.app/Data/data.unity3d' When creating build of unity project in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate build of unity project for iOS. After switching my unity platform to iOS and click on build button, it generates Xcode project for iOS build. When I try to build my game in Xcode for generating build it shows error in log which is following

> -> applicationDidFinishLaunching() Player data archive not found at `/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B0F7097-706C-4290-B882-8667063D4B46/MyGameName.app/Data/data.unity3d`,
>   using local filesystem2018-01-05

I'm tired of googling and searching solution, but didn't found any clue that helps me.

I am using *Unity 5.6.1f1* and *Xcode 9.2*

Thanx in advance....